# Request permission is not working in android 13 or 12

Tags: android, kotlin

I updated my android project from  compileSdkVersion 31 to  compileSdkVersion 33. I have the next code to launch the permissions that I need in the app, but it is not working

```
import android.Manifest
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import android.os.Build



class Permissions(private val activity: Activity, private val permissionList: List<String>, val code: Int) {

    fun checkPermissions() {
        if (permissionsGranted() != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions()
        }
    }

    private fun permissionsGranted(): Int {
        var counter = 0
        for (permission in permissionList) {
            counter += ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, permission)
        }
        return counter
    }

    private fun deniedPermission(): String {
        for (permission in permissionList) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) return permission
        }
        return ""
    }

    private fun requestPermissions() {
        val permission = deniedPermission()
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, permission)) {

        } else {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, permissionList.toTypedArray(), code)
        }
    }

    fun checkPermission(manifest: String): Boolean {
        val result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, manifest)
        return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    fun checkPermissionActivity(state: Boolean, urlPath: String, kind : String){
        val showRationale = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            this.activity.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) && this.activity.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        } else {
            true
        }

        if (!showRationale) {

            return
        } else {

            return
        }
    }

    fun getAllPermissions(): List<String> {
        val granted = ArrayList<String>()
        val pi = activity.packageManager.getPackageInfo(activity.packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS)
        for (i in pi.requestedPermissions.indices) {
            if (pi.requestedPermissionsFlags[i] and PackageInfo.REQUESTED_PERMISSION_GRANTED != 0) {
                granted.add(pi.requestedPermissions[i])
            }
        }

        return granted
    }


}
```

The manifest is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.co.retrofit.app">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <application
            android:name=".feature.RetrofitApplication"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity
                android:exported="true"
                android:name=".feature.view.activities.Maintenance" />
        <activity android:name=".feature.view.activities.SplashActivity"  android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".feature.view.activities.MainActivity"  android:exported="true"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I call the function when I click in one button

```
@Suppress("UNUSED_PARAMETER")
private fun addAlbum(view: View){
    val permissions = Permissions(this,
        arrayListOf(
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
        23)
    permissions.checkPermissions()
}
```

or

```
@Suppress("UNUSED_PARAMETER")
private fun addAlbum(view: View){
    val permissions = Permissions(this,
        arrayListOf(
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA),
        23)
    permissions.checkPermissions()
}
```

If I rollback the updated, it is showing the permission that I need, but I need the compile in 33

[image: evidence]

Now if I only update the compile SDK, it is not showing the popup

[image: Evidence]

Comment: Your ***Permissions.permissionsGranted()*** method may have difficulty distinguishing between normal and dangerous permissions because it is counter-based rather than being specific on each permission. The definitions of dangerous and normal may differ between Android versions.

Answer (score 7):

With **Android 13**, Google Introduced Granular Permissions for Storage meaning you now will have to specify which type of media you want to use in your app.

There are 3 types of permission introduced :

`READ_MEDIA_AUDIO`,
`READ_MEDIA_VIDEO` and
`READ_MEDIA_IMAGES`.

U can no longer request `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission on Android 13, and by no longer I mean no one has been able to identify why. Once u compile for sdk 33, it just stops asking on runtime and removes the permission from the App Settings as well.

Refer to this for more info : https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#granular-media-permissions

Comment: If i want to access the camera. it is not working too @M Ashhal

Comment: @AlejandroGonzalez You might wanna check your merged manifest, there might be a library u are using which might've used maxSdkVersion on camera permission. Check and see if this helps!

Comment: it is correct. now it is working. Thank @M Ashhal

Answer (score 5):

By targeting Android 13, you need to declare in our manifest what kind of media you exactly want to read. You can not request `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in manifest directly.

Suppose you want an audio permission then `READ_MEDIA_AUDIO`, for video permission `READ_MEDIA_VIDEO`, for images `READ_MEDIA_IMAGES` etc.

Also if you are migrating to Android 13 then [this article](https://medium.com/tech-takeaways/migrating-my-app-to-android-13-f5ad0649d23d) can help a lot.

Comment: if I want to access the camara, which is the permission  ?

Comment: For accessing the camera, you'd need android.permission.CAMERA

Comment: @AlejandroGonzalez I think there is no change in behaviour of camera permissions in android 13

Comment: glad to help, you can appreciated by accepting if you want :)

Comment: Why not provide some examples of how to make this work, this would improve your response greatly.